# Java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: java, deprecated

I have written a code for my project and I am getting a warning message when I compile. I could not run it. Having tried many possible ways like ignoring warning and etc, I am still unable to run it. Below you will find the code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.event.*;
 import java.sql.*;

  class NymbleServer extends JFrame 
 {
 JLabel jl1;
 JLabel jl2;


 JButton jb1;
 JButton jb2;

 JTextField jt1;
 JPasswordField jt2;
 String msg="";


 Container c;
 ImageIcon ii;
 ImageIcon i2;
 JLabel jl4;
 JLabel jl6;


 String str="";
 String pass="";
 String path="";
 String coreaddr="";
 String core="";
 String nextcore="";
 String dest="";
 String dest1="";
 File f;
 File fgs;
 Vector v = new Vector();

 NymbleServer()

 {

     jl1=new JLabel("Nymble Server Name ");
     jl2=new JLabel("Server Key ");


     jb1=new JButton("Send");
     jb2=new JButton("Reset");

     jt1=new JTextField(10);
     jt2=new JPasswordField(10);
     ii=new ImageIcon("nymbleserver.png");
     i2=new ImageIcon("nymbleserver1.PNG");
     jl4=new JLabel(ii);
     jl6=new JLabel(i2);

     c = getContentPane();
     c.setLayout(null);
     c.setBackground(new Color(0,0,120));
     c.show();
     c.add(jl1);
     c.add(jt1);
     c.add(jl2);
     c.add(jb1);
     c.add(jb2);
     c.add(jl4);
     c.add(jl6);
     c.add(jt2);

        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            exitForm(evt);
        }
    });





     jl4.setBounds(30,20,728,68);
     jl1.setBounds(20,110,200,25);
     jt1.setBounds(150,110,100,25);
     jl2.setBounds(50,145,200,25);
     jt2.setBounds(150,145,100,25);
     jb1.setBounds(70,235,100,25);
     jb2.setBounds(180,235,100,25);
     jl6.setBounds(300,105,485,309);




     setSize(800,500);
     setVisible(true);
     setTitle("Server");





    jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {


            try {   

  if(!jt1.getText().equals("") && !jt2.getText().equals("")){

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Authorised User", "Login 

Seccess", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

         VerifAdminLogin();

         }
         else
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, 

       "Invalid password. Please try again. ", "Login Error", 

       JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
        catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e);
        }

        }
    });



    jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
        jt1.setText("");
        jt2.setText("");
        } 
        });



     }

     private void exitForm(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) 
    {
    dispose();
     }  

 public static void main(String a[])

 {
     new FileOpen();
 }

 void VerifAdminLogin() 
    {
            Connection con=null;
            String url="jdbc:odbc:nymble";
            Statement st=null;

          try
          {

                     String val1=jt1.getText();
                     val1 = val1.trim();
                     String val2 =  

             (String)jt2.getText();
                     val2 = val2.trim();            



                Class.forName

              ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);

                st = con.createStatement();


            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select Key from 

               Server where SerName='"+val1+"'");

            while(rs.next()){
                String user = rs.getString(1);

                boolean b=user.equals(val2);            



                if(b)
                {

                  new Server().setVisible(true);
            }
                 else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

          ((Component) null, "Invalid password. Please try again. ", "Login Error", 

           JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    jt1.setText("");
                    jt2.requestFocus();
                }
                }
          }
          catch(SQLException ex)
           {
            System.out.println("Unable to access the database");
           }
          catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
           {
            System.out.println("Class not found");
           }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
           System.out.println("Exception raised is:"+ex);
          }
          finally {
          con=null;
          }
    }

      }
```

Comment: On which line of the code is the warning appearing on?

Comment: A *warning* shouldn't stop you from running the program (although you should still fix it). How are you trying to run it, and what happens (exactly) when you try? (I've just managed to start it after receiving the warning - which is about `show()`, by the way.)

Comment: i got it Sir.Biman solved .. thank u for fast response ..Zavior and Jon Skeet

Answer (score 2):

Just replace

```
new PseudonymManager().show();
```

with

```
new PseudonymManager().setVisible(true);
```

Method show() was deprecated since java 1.5 so just read java docs next time;)

Comment: sir i have another code with the same warning message but this time its not working..

Comment: Where did you find PseudonymManager in the provided code?!

Comment: @ErstwhileIII There was other code before. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22115318/1